# Error when updating device via CreateOrUpdateIndividualEnrollmentAsync with IoT DPS

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

The error below occurred when an existing device that has been enrolled with IoT DPS is updated with the code below:

> Executed 'MyFunction' (Failed, Id=xxx)
>        System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: MyFunction. Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Service: Conflict:
>
> {"errorCode":409201,"trackingId":"xxx","message":"Enrollment already
>   exists.","timestampUtc":"2019-08-07T16:27:23.3403783Z"}.
>
> ```
> Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Service errorCode 409201 "Enrollment already exists."
> ```

```
private static async Task UpdateIndividualEnrollmentSymmetricKeyAsync()
            {
    var regId = GetRegistrationId("1", APP_NAME);
    var symmKey = GenerateSymmetricalKey(regId, _PROVISIONING_SHARED_KEY);

    Attestation attestation = new SymmetricKeyAttestation(symmKey, symmKey);
    var enrollment = new IndividualEnrollment(regId, attestation);

   //There are other properties, ProvisioningStatus below is only updated.
    enrollment.ProvisioningStatus = ProvisioningStatus.Enabled;

     //error occurred
    IndividualEnrollment enrollmentResult = await _provisioningServiceClient.CreateOrUpdateIndividualEnrollmentAsync(enrollment);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/f09765cc11a8ab75da6443fa1742403d4b818c6c/provisioning/Samples/service/EnrollmentSample/EnrollmentSample.cs#L95) on how to update an existing individual enrollment:

You should retrieve the existing individual enrollment before updating it and then calling *CreateOrUpdateIndividualEnrollmentAsync*